# Missing Operating System-Laptop dual boot with Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub-efi

I can't boot to Ubuntu or Windows.  When my computer starts, it shows the 'Missing operating system' error.  I tried to use boot repair, but it didn't work.  Here is the report: paste.ubuntu.com/pIWgQ94fBTXtQ.

Comment: Do You have multiple hard drives?

Comment: Please copy & paste link so it works. What brand/model system? What video card/chip? If you installed in UEFI boot mode, do you have UEFI set to boot in UEFI mode or legacy/CSM/BIOS boot mode which then would not work?

Comment: Can you access **BIOS Setup** screen? Restart your system, press `del` key and reach BIOS setup screen. You will observe a set of bootloaders. Can you please list them?

Answer (score 0):

If grub loads, press C to load a command shell and try

```
ls
root=(hd1,1)
chainloader +1
boot
```

With ls a list of systems that could be loaded will be printed. Try some combinations if `root=(hd1,1)` doesn't work. For example (hd1,0), (hd2,1) etc.